# How do I save a local variable within a factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have this example

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  @site = FactoryGirl.create(:my_site)
  factory :user do
    email               { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name          { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name           { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password            { 'TarXlrOPfaokNOzls2U8' }
    active_directory    { '0' }
    companies           { [FactoryGirl.create(:company, site: @site)] }
    sites               { [@site] }
  end
end
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a let or something...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email               { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name          { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name           { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password            { 'TarXlrOPfaokNOzls2U8' }
    active_directory    { '0' }
    companies           { [FactoryGirl.create(:company, site: FactoryGirl.create(:my_site))] }
    sites               { [FactoryGirl.create(:my_site)] }

  end
end
```

This works but it creates two my_site which is a Site object but I need them to be the same...any idea on how to achieve this

Comment: what's the problem with a local variable? `site = FactoryGirl.create(:my_site)`

Comment: your right that did work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the simplest is to use a local variable:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  site = FactoryGirl.create(:my_site)

  factory :user do
    email               { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name          { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name           { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password            { 'TarXlrOPfaokNOzls2U8' }
    active_directory    { '0' }
    companies           { [FactoryGirl.create(:company, site: site)] }
    sites               { [site] }
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it only creates the `site` variable once.  if i want a variable created each time factorybot runs (like `my_rand_number = Random.rand(1..10)`), i would only get one random number and it would be the same number every time i create a new model instance.  do you know how to get a different random number with each `FactoryBot.create(:my_site)` statement?

Answer (score 6):

I finally figured out a good way to do this. This question is pretty old, but I thought I'd post an answer in case other people come across this.

You can use a `before(:create)` callback (or `before(:build)` if thats your use case) to set the `sites` collection, and then assign the first element of the sites collection to the newly created company in the company collection.

More information about FactoryBot callbacks can be found [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl).

Just so readers know, I'm using the new `FactoryBot` class name as `FactoryGirl` is deprecated.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email               { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name          { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name           { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password            { 'TarXlrOPfaokNOzls2U8' }
    active_directory    { '0' }

    before(:create) do |user|
      user.sites << FactoryBot.create(:my_site)
      user.companies << FactoryBot.create(:company, site: user.sites.first)
    end
  end
end
```